# javascript .load feature not working for a specific bit of coding

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7

my navigation is not working in IE7 or IE8 on site www.garden-design-courses.co.uk

I am pulling the file for the navigation through using:

```
function loadTopmenu() 
{ 
   $("#topmenu").load("http://www.garden-design-courses.co.uk/lib/topmenu.html");
   }
```

I am using this for the footer and the header and works fine, which leads me to believe its due to the javascript within the file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("ul.subnav").parent().append("<span></span>"); //Only shows drop down trigger when js is enabled - Adds empty span tag after ul.subnav
    $("ul.subnav2").parent().append("<span></span>"); //Only shows drop down trigger when js is enabled - Adds empty span tag after ul.subnav

    $("ul.topnav li span").click(function() { //When trigger is clicked...

        //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click

        $(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function(){  
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
        });

        //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
        }).hover(function() { 
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function(){  //On Hover Out
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
    });


    $("a.dip").click(function() { //When trigger is clicked...

        //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click

        $(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function(){  
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
        });

        //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
        }).hover(function() { 
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function(){  //On Hover Out
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
    });

    $("a.dip2").click(function() { //When trigger is clicked...

        //Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
        $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav2").slideDown('fast').show(); //Drop down the subnav on click

        $(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function(){  
            $(this).parent().find("ul.subnav2").slideUp('slow'); //When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
        });

        //Following events are applied to the trigger (Hover events for the trigger)
        }).hover(function() { 
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //On hover over, add class "subhover"
        }, function(){  //On Hover Out
            $(this).removeClass("subhover"); //On hover out, remove class "subhover"
    });

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try deleting that http://www.garden-design-courses.co.uk from url, it might be that problem. but probably wouldnt

Comment: thanks but thats not done anything

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
$("#topmenu").load("http://www.garden-design-courses.co.uk/lib/topmenu.html", function (a,b,c) {console.log(a,b,c);});
```

And check if it gives you an error instead of the expected content on your console.